# View messages in celery/rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Hy,

Is there a way to see the messages that arr waiting in the Celery/RabbitMQ queues?
I would like to see what parameters has each waiting task.

Tx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

**UPD:**

Message props and headers are plain strings or numbers so you can view them without any extra job.

If you need to see message body and [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)  doesn't fits you, another approach is to consume messages from queue, output their content and push them back in queue. There is some chance to loose message during such action if your script fail before message will be requeued back.

Again, if you need to see only parameters or headers then [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) is your best friend.

If you send JSON or XML encoded message body i think it is trivial to write js script and use it with [Userscripts](http://userscripts.org/) to show you message original content.

Comment: Your question was about props. They are not encoded. I updated my answer.